# Android Torch App not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, flashlight

If i give permission manually than it works. Rather than that it doesn't work. Can any one help me. What change should i made. I am new to android development. I can't find anything on google.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.plutianclub.flashlight">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_flashlight_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.plutianclub.flashlight;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton imageButton;

Camera camera;
Camera.Parameters parameters;
boolean isFlash = false;
boolean isOn = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.offButton);

    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)){
        camera = Camera.open();
        parameters = camera.getParameters();
        isFlash = true;
    }

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlash == true){
                if (isOn == false  ){
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                    camera.startPreview();
                    isOn = true;

                }else {
                    imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
                    parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    camera.setParameters(parameters);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    isOn = false;
                }

            }else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Error....");
                builder.setMessage("Flashlight is not avilable on this device.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (camera != null){
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it Also, [there is no `FLASHLIGHT` permission in Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)` Android requires that you ask permission by code at runtime or at the time when the feature are gonna be used.

There are more about here with examples. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Anything below `Android 6.0` will just require as you already have done it in the manifest